# Regular Expression to check starting and ending of a email id to check bounced users

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to check for bounced users from a list.

user_testfirstname@companyit.com = correct

user_testfirstname@gmail.com = incorrect

users_testfirstname@companyit.com = correct

it should start with either user_ or users_ and end with @companyit.com

only starts with is there i need a combination of both as above.

```
$email_id = "user_test@companyid.com";

if (preg_match("#^user_(.*)$#i", $email_id)){ 

echo 'bounced'; 

}
else{

echo 'registered';

}
```

Any suggestions ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `should start with either user_ or users_ and end with @companyit.com`

Try this regex:

```
preg_match("#^users?_(.*?)@companyit\.com$#i", $email_id);
```